# How do I work with list elements? | PYTHON

Tags: python, arrays, list, encoding, hex

I have a list, for example `['exa', 'mp', 'l', 'e']`.

I need to work with each element to hexlify it. How do I want to do it? At first, I want to get each element somehow and then do hex(element). How do I get it? Or may be I can just hexlify the whole list?

Thanks in advance.

I want to say that I tried `str(listname)`, but it just outputs `"['exa', 'mp', 'l', 'e']"` which doesn't fulfill my expectations.

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: I haven't tried anything but str(list), it doesn't work

Comment: What do you mean under `hex(element)`? Python's built-in `hex` function expects integer number but your element are `str`s.

Comment: Well, that's precisely what we want to see. Please update the question with this code and the output it produces and a reason why this doesn't fulfill your expectations.

Comment: Ok, that's better. So about those expectations, what are they exactly?

Comment: I want to see "exa", "mp", "l", "e" as, like, different variables or anything. But also as another option I want to hexlify the whole list and then separate it in variables like "hexvar", "otherhexvar", "lasthexvar"

Comment: Hmm, that's not very clear. Any way what exactly is `hexlify`? Also the `separate it in variables` seems a lot like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables) which is a no-no.

Comment: Hexlify is to make it in hex. Example: transform "exa", "mp", "l", "e" into "657861", "6d70",  
"6c", "65"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `hexlify` thing you are asking for can be done like this:

```
listname = ['exa', 'mp', 'l', 'e']
print([item.encode('utf-8').hex() for item in listname])
```

Output:

```
['657861', '6d70', '6c', '65']
```

Answer (score 5):

Use list comprehension:

```py
result = [hex(x) for x in arr]
```

Comment: Can also use map() instead :)

Comment: Yes, arr is your original list. List comprehension iterates through the list (each item is ```x```) and performs the operation ```hex(x)``` and stores it in result. There are a lot more complicated things you can do, but those are the basics

Comment: This gives `TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer` as the array contains strings.

Comment: Yes, because you can't use ```hex()``` with strings.

Comment: I will use binascii to hexlify with strings, don't worry.